# Is it possible to have nodes from multiple datacenters join the same Spark cluster?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am running a Datastax Enterprise cluster (with `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`). I have two datacenters, `Analytics` and `Cassandra`. `Analytics` nodes forms a Spark cluster. I am considering merging the two clusters to better utilize resources.

When I enable Spark (in `/etc/dse/default`) on my `Cassandra` nodes I get a new master and it seems like those nodes aren't joining the same Spark cluster as the `Analytics` nodes. Can I somehow make the `Cassandra` datacenter nodes join the `Analytics` Spark cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch, you must also change which DC the new Spark nodes are in. Otherwise they will continue to be in the so-named "Cassandra" datacenter.

Edit:
The short answer to your headline questions is "No". Separate DC's are assigned separate spark masters and don't share resources on spark jobs.

Comment: The default, not-recommended-for-production DseSimpleSnitch would have automatically detected the change.